# Проблема со слэшем в конце ссылки

Tags: apache, nginx

На моём сервере nginx проксирует, а apache стоит за ним. Возникает такая проблема, что когда я пишу ссылку в виде: `https://example.com/orders/`, то всё в порядке.  А если в конце не дописываю слэш, то страница просто не загружается и возникает Conection Timed Out. И я никак не могу разобраться, чья это вина - apache2 или nginx. В чём проблема?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jamesjgoodwin.ru www.jamesjgoodwin.ru;

    location ~ /.ht { deny all; }

    location / {
        if ($http_host ~ "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}") {
            return 444;
        }
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://jamesjgoodwin.ru$1 permanent;
    }

    location ~* \.(html|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|css|js|pdf|txt|tar|ico)$ {
        root /var/www/;
        expires 30d;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name jamesjgoodwin.ru www.jamesjgoodwin.ru;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/jamesjgoodwin.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/jamesjgoodwin.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
        index   index.html index.php;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это ни баг nginx, ни баг httpd.

Вам нужно писать `<a href="/orders/hydrosystems/">link</a>`, а вариант `<a href="/orders/hydrosystems">link</a>` в вашем случае -- НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ.

Смотрите.

Когда вы запрашиваете имя со слэшем на конце это значит, что запрашивается папка (в примере -- orders), а значит - должен показываться файл index.html который лежит в этой папке.

Когда вы запрашиваете без слэша на конце -- это значит, что запрашивается файл orders (без расширения).

В данном конфиге у вас нет вины ни nginx, ни apache: что вы в браузере подаёте -- то и передаётся (сначала на nginx, потом - на апач).

PS И не стоит кривизну неправильных ссылок исправлять костылями в nginx или httpd, хотя такие способы есть (`DirectorySlash on` в конфиге апача).

Comment: У меня есть папка /orders/hydrosystems и в папке hydrosystems есть index.html, но если я открою папку hydrosystems без слэша, то и сайт внутри этой папки не откроется. И помимо этой папки есть и остальные. Так что устанавливать правила для каждой отдельно взятой папки - не вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения подобной задачи использую .htaccess и подобные правила

```
# Редирект для категорий (чтобы в конце URL был /)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.xml$
RewriteRule (.+) $1/ [R=301,L]
```